# Python dict of lists down to dict of single items matching indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I cannot find a similar question with this use case.

I have a dictionary containing lists and I want to extract a particular index from each list and have that assigned in a new dict with the same key.

```
dict1 = {
 'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'key2': ['d', 'e']
}
```

into

```
dict2 = {  # taking index 1 of each list
  'key1': 'b',
  'key2': 'e'
}
```

This cannot be done with dict.update and I cannot find a built-in way for doing this without manually iterating over each key, which isn't pythonic.

Comment: `dict2 = {k: v[1] for k,v in dict1.items()}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "manually iterating over each key", iteration isn't really manual is it, plus you're going to have to inspect each item some how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
dict1 = {
 'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 'key2': ['d', 'e']
}
```

Just simple single line that checks if the index exists in the list 
(otherwise will add None to the key)
*EDIT thanks to @RoadRunner's suggestion

```
n = 1
dict2 = {k:v[n] if len(v) > n else None for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

OR
a different approach, sort of more pythonic EAFP approach:

```
dict2 = {}
n = 1

for k,v in dict1.items():
    try:
        dict2[k] = v[n]
    except IndexError:
        dict2[k] = None
```

Comment: In this specific case (declaring a literal dict) on newer versions of python this will work, but in general I don't think it's useful to assume the dict items will come back in the order we expect.

Comment: @RoadRunner I've missed that the keys were the original ones from the first dict, fixed it

Comment: @glibdud the question had a tag of python-3.x, but why does the order matters ? it's a dictionary the order doesn't matter

Comment: @Oleg No worries. I upvoted because you also handle the cases where an `IndexError` could be raised. For your first example, you could also do `dict2 = {k:v[n] if len(v) > n else None for k,v in dict1.items()}`.

Comment: @Oleg If the keys were declared in the opposite order (`key2` first, then `key1`), then your previous solution using enumerate would have produced incorrect results. Your edit looks better.

Comment: I was blanking on using a dictionary literal, thanks @Oleg also the eafp solution is also more readable.

Comment: I control the lists and assuming lengths are matching or less is sufficient coverage.